# how to check whether my app has the permission in always or when in use in ios using xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using xamarin.forms for my app and i am using ios device. I want to check  whether my app is using "Always" or "While Using the App" for location in iOS.

```
var LocationStatus1 = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.LocationAlways);
                if (LocationStatus1 == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    LocationLabel.Text = "Location Always";
                }
                var LocationStatus2 = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.LocationWhenInUse);
                if (LocationStatus2 == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    LocationLabel.Text = "Location When In Use";
                }
```

I expect that when my app has the permission like "Always", then LocationStatus1 comes true or "While Using the App" means it comes LocationStatus2 comes true. But now LocationStatus1 and LocationStatus2 comes true. So Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You will need to have a look at the implementation of CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync or read its document if it's 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause:**

**CrossPermissions** can not get the different between Always and WhenInUse because it is only in iOS .

**Solution:**

You can implement it in native iOS platform and get it by using **DependencyService**.

Refer to the following code

> in Forms

Define an Interface

```
namespace xxx
{
  public interface ICheckLocationStatus
  {
    int CheckLocationStatus();
  }
}
```

> in iOS project

```
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using CoreLocation;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetLocationStatus))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class GetLocationStatus : ICheckLocationStatus
    {
        public int CheckLocationStatus()
        {

            var status = CLLocationManager.Status;

            if(status== CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            else if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            else if (status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
            {
                return 2;
            }

            else 
            {
                return 3;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And call the method in forms (For example when you click a button)

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    int status = DependencyService.Get<ICheckLocationStatus>().CheckLocationStatus();

    if (status == 0)
    {
       DisplayAlert("Title", "Location Always", "Cancel");
    }

    else if (status == 1)
    {
       DisplayAlert("Title", "Location WhenInUse", "Cancel");
    }

    else if (status == 2)
    {
       DisplayAlert("Title", "Location Denied", "Cancel");
    }

    else
    {
       DisplayAlert("Title", "Location Unknown", "Cancel");
    }

}
```